# rails server not serving git files of current branch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I setup a rails project and started working in a specific branch (`branch1`). I was doing ok with `rails s` until I wanted to setup another branch (`branch2`) with different files. I did `git fetch origin branch2` for getting the second branch, and was doing fine configuring this branch (`bundle`, `rake db:setup`, etc...) up until running `rails s`. When I start my server, it should serve the files of my current checkout branch (`branch2`) but it serves the files of the previous branch I was working on (`branch1`).

**Things I tried:**

- Thought `git fetch` won't actually get the remote branch to my workspace for the server to load up the correct files. So I deleted the fetched branch and did `git checkout -b branch2 origin/branch2`. Server still loads files in `branch1`.
- Did `spring stop` so the server don't load up files stored in the cache (I was told this... I don't really know how spring works). Still, server loads files in `branch1`
- I cloned the repository again, and set up everything for `branch2`. But still `rails s` manages to load `branch1` (I would say that `branch1` is the default when you clone the repo)

**What I expect:**

- Doing `rails s` in checkout `branch1` should load and display app in `branch1`.
- Doing `rails s` in checkout `branch2` should load and display app in `branch2`.

Any help would be really really REALLY appreciated, I've been stuck with this for hours now... thanks in advance.

P.S. The branches share the same database, I don't if that would help but I thought it was worth mentioning

Comment: Have you tried `rake tmp:clear` ?

Comment: Just tried that. The problem persists :(

Comment: If by git files you mean assets you should clear precompiled assets and cache using `rails tmp:cache:clear assets:clobber`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks for the help on the comments**, unfortunately those answers didn't work for me.

Turns out, the server was loading the app correctly in `localhost` but because the navigation menu on the project is too big, it was saved in the cache to optimize the load in every branch. So I needed to run a script for changing the navigation menu (the script was provided to me by my colleagues that were in the project long before me).

So if you have this problem, ask your colleagues, contributors, boss if there is something you are missing.